# query did not work as sudden android studio jtds

Tags: android-studio, jdbc, sql-update, logcat

I'm using jtds style to connect and do update and insert in my MSSQL Server. Everything works just fine but suddenly my program did not read the query anymore and thus show the error messages. From the logCat, there aren't error in my coding, but error within the device. Please help me how to solves this problem.

my full code:

```
  public class ResumeAll extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;


        String OperatorPF = txt_PFNO.getText().toString();
        //        String BreakReason = txt_reason.getText().toString();
//      String PIC = lblname.getText().toString();
        //        String IPCpf = txt_IPC.getText().toString();
        String a_status = "Active";
        String b_status = "Break";
        String PIC = lblname.getText().toString();


        ;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
            //bbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(Resume.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (isSuccess) {
//                Intent i = new Intent(Operation.this, Start_Page.class);
//                startActivity(i);
//                finish();


            }

        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {

                    String dates = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    String currentTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
//

                    String query1 = "select * from WORKTR where status='" + b_status + "' and Start_date ='" + dates + "' ";
                    Statement sm = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet result = sm.executeQuery(query1);


                    if (result.next()) {


                        Statement st = con.createStatement();
                        String query = ("Update BRTR set end_break ='" + currentTime + "',status ='" + a_status + "' where status='" + b_status + "' and work_date='" + dates + "' and Scan_by ='" + PIC + "'");
                        st.executeUpdate(query);
                        String query2 = ("Update WORKTR set status ='" + a_status + "' where Start_date='" + dates + "' and status='" + b_status + "' and Scan_by ='" + PIC + "'");
                        st.executeUpdate(query2);
                        isSuccess = true;
                        z = "ResumeTime Recorded";
                    } else {
                        isSuccess = false;
                        z = "Error occured. Please check for your attendance";

                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                isSuccess = false;
                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);

            }


            return z;
        }


    }
```

error in LogCat:

```
2020-01-10 16:14:35.983 2097-2796/? E/aodc: Phenotype API error. Event # caxd@eaefca89, EventCode: 12 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    aoby: 29503
        at aodi.b(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):29)
        at aodc.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):95)
        at aodc.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):81)
        at aaoz.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):7)
        at blso.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):2)
        at szp.b(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):15)
        at szp.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):10)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at tfn.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-01-10 16:14:35.984 2097-2796/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetCommittedConfigurationOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 29503, resolution=null}]
        at aodc.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):96)
        at aodc.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):81)
        at aaoz.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):7)
        at blso.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):2)
        at szp.b(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):15)
        at szp.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):10)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at tfn.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-01-10 16:14:35.986 2097-3432/? E/NetRec: [157] albw.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: rtt: 29503: 
        at auzw.b(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):5)
        at auzw.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):20)
        at albw.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):1)
        at albw.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):4)
        at albv.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):2)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):20)
        at ssr.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):1)
        at bpc.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):1)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):10)
        at sss.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):17)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):6)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):2)
     Caused by: rtt: 29503: 
        at rzj.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):4)
        at aoav.b(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):3)
        at aodi.a(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):7)
        at aaoz.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):15)
        at blso.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):2)
        at szp.b(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):15)
        at szp.run(:com.google.android.gms@19831029@19.8.31 (100406-284611645):10)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at tfn.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-01-10 16:14:36.328 1402-1402/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast android.battery.extend.QCOM_BATTERY_MANAGER_HELPER from system 1402:system/1000 pkg android
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:21370)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:21881)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:22116)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1185)
        at com.android.server.BatteryService$12.run(BatteryService.java:1648)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:476)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:304)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2020-01-10 16:14:36.361 1402-1402/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast android.battery.extend.QCOM_BATTERY_MANAGER_HELPER from system 1402:system/1000 pkg android
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:21370)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:21974)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:22116)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcastAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1185)
        at com.android.server.BatteryService$12.run(BatteryService.java:1648)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:476)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:304)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
```

Please help me :(

Comment: Those exception stacktraces don't seem related to the code you show

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  yes sir,  Thank you for respond. That's what shown in the stacktrace and I alert that is not about my code. Still, I can say that when installed, the device did not show the toast message even though the codes run well. Do you have any idea what is the stacktrace report about?